# Want to start a new activity on fire of Alarmanager event independent of task creating the alarmmanager event

Tags: android

I am setting a reminder using `AlarmManager` from my application. On firing of alarm event, i am starting an `Activity`, Alarmdetails.

The issue is that as the activity starts it also brought forward the task of application. I tried many things including putting `FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. But nothing works out properly.

Using these flags giving another problem. Please help me out. 
Here is the main code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,AlarmDetails.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

i.putExtra("hr", hr);
i.putExtra("min", min);
i.putExtra("message", label);

PendingIntent displayIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            displayIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK` as you suggested, but launched the activity from within a BroadcastReceiver class.

Setting the alarm:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

And the receiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, MyAlarmActivity.class);
        newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
        context.startActivity(newIntent);
    }
}
```

This works for me. When the alarm goes off, a new Task with MyAlarmActivity is created - and if I go BACK from that new Activity I end up wherever I was before the alarm went off.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue, by using

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

and every thing worked like charm.